Windows laptop with 2 DDR4 slots and space for 2 NVME
I want to migrate some items of my current computer into a new one
I have

2 x 16GB DDR4 3200MT/s Non-ECC Unbuffered SODIMM
NVME 2280

I want a recommendation for a Windows laptop with 2 NVMe slots (one for 2280)
and 2 slots for my RAM

The Framework laptop 13th gen sounds like it perfectly meets your needs. Why Framework?
It supports NVME M.2 2280 for storage. As well as DDR4 for memory.
For a $1,000 budget

CPU: Intel i5-1340P
RAM: none (bring your own)
Storage: none (bring your own)
Power adapter: Power Adapter - 60W - US/Canada

For a $1,500 budget

CPU: Intel i7-1370P
RAM: none (bring your own)
Storage: none (bring your own)
Power adapter: Power Adapter - 60W - US/Canada

Buy it here
